# Disable read-only flag on git object and pack files

Tags: sync, git, nas

In all my local git repos all of the object and pack files (.git\object\pack) are read-only... I understand why this is but it's really messing with my attempt to sync my machine to my Synology NAS. First, yes, I have looked into fixing it on the sync software side, but for whatever dumb reason, they won't let you sync read-only files (I kind of get it, but at least let me turn it off!).

So, is there a way to disable git object and pack files from being read-only in the first place? Can't find anything in the git docs. I solemnly swear I won't ever manually edit those files :)

Comment: Syncing git repo doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: It's just a backup